# How to publish PowerApps using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I am trying to use the PowerShell command to publish a PowerApps. I have the prerequisites installed in my system. I am able to get the app details using the PowerApps command.
But unable to publish, as when I am trying to see the Publish-AdminPowerApps cmdlet, I did not able to get it. But got the Publish-PowerApps cmdlet. I tryied using that by providng the appname with the respective app guid.

Example:

```
Publish-PowerApp -AppName 80c0a051-3322-1247-8146-83fa6480a724
```

After the command executes I receive the below response. Although when I see and look at the actual app version there is not publishing made.

```
Code Description Internal
---- ----------- --------
 200 OK
```

Kindly help me with this.

Note: I am an administrator in PowerApps platform

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Import the necessary modules using the following commands:

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell -AllowClobber
```

[image]
2.Try to use `Publish-AdminPowerApp`
(previously Publish-App)
[image]
Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell

Comment: While trying to use Publish-AdminPowerApp cmdlet error throwing as 'Publish-AdminPowerApp is not recognized as a cmdlet'

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to import the necessary modules first.

Comment: I followed the same previously as well as did it one more time, but same issue. I am able to see all the cmdlets except the 'Publish-AdminPowerApp'. This cmdlets is also greyed out inside the MSDN article you have mentioned above. SO, looks like Microsoft has disabled that publishing option from PowerShell. If I am correct any other way I can publish the PowerApps except the manual intervention.